# Linq GroupBy throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two tables

```
Animals           Activities
+----+-------+    +----+------------+----------+------------+
| Id | Name  |    | Id | Activity   | FkAnimal | Date       |
+----+-------+    +----+------------+----------+------------+
| 1  | Cats  |    | 1  | Ball       | 2        | 2015-05-21 |
+----+-------+    +----+------------+----------+------------+
| 2  | Dogs  |    | 2  | Pet        | 2        | 2015-06-07 |
+----+-------+    +----+------------+----------+------------+
| 3  | Birds |    | 3  | Running    | 1        | 2014-11-03 |
+----+-------+    +----+------------+----------+------------+
                  | 4  | Kill a fly | 1        | 2014-08-05 |
                  +----+------------+----------+------------+
                  | 5  | Kill a fly | 3        | 2014-08-05 |
                  +----+------------+----------+------------+
```

What I want is the result of this query

```
SELECT Animals.Name, Animals.Id, Activities.Data
FROM Activities
INNER JOIN Animals ON Animals.Id = Activities.Id
GROUP BY Animals.Name, Animals.Data
```

In LINQ from the Entity Framework

Here's my attempt:

```
//My repository is of type IRepository<Activities>
var list = Repository.GetAll().GroupBy(a => a.Animals).Select((grouping,i) => new {
    name = grouping.Key.Name,
    id = grouping.Key.Id,
    data = grouping.ElementAt(i).Data
}).ToList();
```

Unfortunately the `ToList()` method generate `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, and if I debug the lambda it shows that `i` goes out of range

Comment: Because `i` is the index of the group.

Comment: Your sql query is wrong...You can't select `Activities.Data` directly without applying aggregation

Comment: The issue is this line: `data = grouping.ElementAt(i).Data`.  What is `data` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

The `i` in `.Select((grouping,i) =>` is the index of the group.  In your example, `.GroupBy(a => a.Animals)` will return an `IGrouping` which is, essentially, just an `IEnumerable` with a `Key` property.  The result from `.GroupBy(a => a.Animals)` will, loosely, look something like this (not sure exactly what your DbContext looks like):

```
{[
    {
        Key: Dogs
        GetEnumerator(): [
            {
                Id: 1
                Activity: Ball
                Date: 2015-05-21
            },
            {
                Id: 2
                Activity: Pet
                Date: 2015-06-07
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Key: Cats
        GetEnumerator(): [
            {
                Id: 3
                Activity: Running
                Date: 2014-11-03
            },
            {
                Id: 4
                Activity: Kill a fly
                Date: 2014-08-05
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Key: Birds
        GetEnumerator(): [
            {
                Id: 5
                Activity: Kill a fly
                Date: 2014-08-05
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

The `Select` method is iterating over the groups, not the elements in the group.  So the `i` in `.Select((grouping,i) =>`, in this case, refers to the index of the group (there are three groups) not an element in a group.  Within your select you are calling `data = grouping.ElementAt(i).Data`, `grouping` in this case is an `IGropuing` which is an `IEnumerable` so `ElementAt(i)` is asking for the ith element in whichever group is currently being evaluated.  By the time you get the third group `i` will be 2 but there is only one element in the group, hence the exception; at least in this example, your groups may come back in a different order but the principle is the same.

You probably want something like this:

```
var list = 
    Repository
    .GetAll()
    .GroupBy(a => a.Animals)
    .Select(grouping => new {
        name = grouping.Key.Name,
        id = grouping.Key.Id,
        data = grouping.Select(x => x)
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work...

```
var res= from act in Repository.GetAll()
       let anm=act.Animals.Single(a=>a.Id=act.FkAnimal)
       select new {
          anm.Id, anm.Name, act.Activity
       };
```